# Are there any characterizations of $C^2$ convex functions?

Tags: convex-optimization, convexity, convex-analysis

There are several characterizations of convex functions with the Lipschitz continuous gradient. If we already know that the function is of class $C^1$, then we have the following equivalent conditions:

> **Theorem.** Let $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be convex and let $L>0$. Then the following conditions (required to hold for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$) are equivalent
>
> 1. $|\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)|\leq L|x-y|$.
> 2. $g(x)=\frac{L}{2}|x|^2-f(x)$ is convex.
> 3. $f(y)\leq f(x)+\langle\nabla f(x),y-x\rangle+\frac{L}{2}|y-x|^2$.
> 4. $\langle \nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y),x-y\rangle\leq L|x-y|^2$.
> 5. $f(y)\geq f(x)+\langle\nabla f(x),y-x\rangle +\frac{1}{2L}|\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)|^2$.
> 6. $\langle\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y),x-y\rangle\geq\frac{1}{L}|\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)|^2$.

There is even a characterization of convex functions with Lipschitz continuous gradient in the class of all convex functions (without assuming a priori $C^1$ regularity as in the above result):

> **Theorem.** For a convex function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ the following conditions are equivalent
>
> 1. There is $L>0$ such that for all $x,h\in\mathbb{R}^n$
>    $$f(x+h) + f(x-h) - 2f(x) \leq L|h|^2.$$
> 2. $f\in C^1$ and $|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)| \leq L|x-y|$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

The above results are well known, but not so easy to find. However you can found them in some monographs on convex analysis.

My questions are:

> **Questions 1.** Are there similar characterizations of $C^2$ convex functions?

I am even interested in weaker questions:

> **Questions 2.** Are there sufficient confitions that guarantee that a convex function is of class $C^2$?

> **Questions 3.** Are there sufficient confitions that guarantee that a convex function of class $C^{1,1}$ is of class $C^2$?

And even a weaker one:

> **Questions 4.** Are there sufficient confitions that guarantee that a strongly convex function is of class $C^2$?

In fact, I am interested in **any** non-trivial results that would imply that a given convex function is of class $C^2$. I am not aware of any such results.

Comment: Are there any conjectures in this regard?

Comment: @PieroD'Ancona I haven't seen any conjectures of this type. My questions are motivated by the results of my paper D. Azagra, P. Hajłasz, Lusin-type properties of convex functions and convex sets. J. Geom. Anal. 31 (2021), 11685–11701.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. In the first theorem it is assumed that $f$ is differentiable and the statement is about Lipschitzness of its gradient. For the analogues result, do you want to assume that $f$ is twice differentiable and characterize Lipschitzness of its Hessian?

Comment: @cheyp I do not know what I want to assume since I do not know any results that would characteriza $C^2$ convex functions. I just want to see nontrivial results showing that a convex function satisfying some conditions is of class $C^2$.